# printer is printing twice

Tags: drivers, printing

```
># echo foo > foo.txt
># lp foo.txt -d DCP9020CDW
request id is DCP9020CDW-3 (1 file(s))

> lpstat -a
DCP9020CDW accepting requests since Wed 13 Jan 2016 10:36:57 PM CET
```

I just installed the driver straight from [brother website using their "driver install tool"](http://support.brother.com/g/b/downloadlist.aspx?c=eu_ot&lang=en&prod=dcp9020cdw_eu&os=128)

Yet every single file including the print test during install, the network configuration report ( asked for from lcd screen on printer itself) and the above foo.txt are printed twice.

Printer works fine on windows 10 from the same physical machine. Both case as network printer.

Any Idea ?

Comment: What happens if you include `-n 1` to specify number of copies as 1 in your `lp` command? also, according to the man page the filename should appear last on your lp line.

Comment: > lp -d DCP9020CDW -n 1 foo.txt 
(same result)

Comment: Did you get any error messages when running the driver install tool? Did you use `sudo` to run it?

Comment: I'm not sure why... But after hours wrestling, I tried the ultimate technique. Reboot,Update,Reboot. And then it was printing only once. I guess either the reboot or some driver updates ?

Comment: The command `cat /var/log/dpkg.log` may give you some clues as to whether an update resolved the problem for you.

Answer (score 0):

Open Printers, Right Click on the printer in question and choose Properties, Select Job Options and insure Copies is set to 1 as shown:

[image: copies]

Comment: (checked) It is set to 1 .